# How do I turn a phrase into an adjective

Tags: relative-clauses

日本語が分からない人
Is a phrase that means a man who doesn't understand japanese but how does this grammar work I mean you do I turn a whole phrase into an adjective do I have to but the inter phrase and then add a noun?

Answer (score 3):

It will never become an "adjective" whatever you do with it. But you can make it be a clause that acts as a qualifier. Just as 日本語の分からない qualifies 人.

If you use a verb:

> **この人が食べた**ケーキ。 : The cake that **this person ate**

If you use an adjective:

> **優しい**この人。 : This person, who **is nice**

Other examples:

> **目の前に現れた**人。 : The person that **appeared in front of my eyes**
>
> **机の上にいる**猫。 : The cat that **is on the desk**

The noun that comes after the verb/adjective is qualified by the previous relative clause.